# How to get play datasource instance when using slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, pac4j

I am using play-slick with slick evolutions to create my db.

I have the following config

```
slick.dbs.default.profile="slick.jdbc.H2Profile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

This works fine when I want to use slick itself to operate on the db. However, I want to access the underlying `javax.sql.Datasource` instance (which I need to pass in to another library, namely pac4js `DbProfileService`).

I tried to add a config for the db name as `dbName="play"`, and then add

```
  @Provides
  def dbProfileService(dbApi: DBApi): DbProfileService = {
    new DbProfileService(dbApi.database(configuration.get[String]("dbName")).dataSource)
  }
```

however, it seems that the injection happens before the evolution script has a chance to run, which causes an exception saying that the `play` database isn't able to be found.
Is there a better approach for this problem?

Here is the stack trace

```
aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find database for play
    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter.$anonfun$database$1(DBApiAdapter.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.getOrElse(Map.scala:248)
    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter.database(DBApiAdapter.scala:32)
    at modules.SecurityModule.dbProfileService(SecurityModule.scala:53)
    at modules.SecurityModule$$FastClassByGuice$$153731.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
    at modules.SecurityModule$$FastClassByGuice$$153731.apply(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:260)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:60)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.inject(SingleFieldInjector.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers(MembersInjectorImpl.java:146)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectAndNotify(MembersInjectorImpl.java:101)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer$InjectableReference.get(Initializer.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.Initializer.injectAll(Initializer.java:140)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
```

I also added a breakpoint, and sure enough, there was only the `default` db there, not the `play` db as I would expect.

Comment: Seems surprising to me. Pretty sure I've seen cases of a class using the `DBApi` in a similar way and evolutions were run before. Could you maybe expand what makes you think evolutions didn't run?

Comment: @GaëlJ I added the stack trace to the post, plus verified it by adding a breakpoint at `def dbProfileService` and `DBApi.databases` only has the `default` database, not the `play` database.

Comment: just guessing. you are using the config properties from [play-slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlaySlick), mean while `DbApi` belongs to `jdbc` module of play and uses other key properties for [jdbc configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Databases-configuration)

Comment: I saw that play-slick [uses dbapi internally](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/0af40dd12f411f4a1471acc9c8b6a4dd8a7af883/src/evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/evolutions/EvolutionsModule.scala#L15)
but maybe I didn't understand something.

Comment: [slick configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlaySlick#Database-Configuration) keys start with `slick` prefix, mean while [jdbc config](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase#Databases-configuration) don't. The key for the url of the default db is `slick.dbs.default.url` for slick, mean while for jdbc is `db.default.url`. Not sure if it could be that the problem you are having trying to get the configuration of an specific db based on the db name.

Comment: is it possible to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? are you trying to do that from a new module? are you overriding the default application loader?

Comment: @GastónSchabas I made a minimal reproducible example [here](https://github.com/AhoCaveman/SampleProject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the value of the key `dbName`. When you are doing

```scala
configuration.get[String]("dbName")
```

You are looking up for the value of the key named `dbName` that is in your config files. In the provided example, the value is `play`. Now, looking at the complete line you have this

```scala
@Provides
def dbProfileService(dbApi: DBApi): DbProfileService = {
  new DbProfileService(
    dbApi                                   // trait play.api.db.DBApi
      .database(                            // method from `DBApi`
        configuration.get[String]("dbName") // getting the value of the key `dbName` from config file
      )
      .dataSource 
    )
}
```

You are calling the `database` method from `DBApi`. There are two classes that are mixing this trait. One is [DBApiAdapter](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/5.1.0/src/evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/slick/evolutions/internal/DBApiAdapter.scala) from `play-slick-evolutions` and the other one is [DefaultDBApi](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.8.20/persistence/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/DefaultDBApi.scala) from `play-jdbc`. I think in your case is using the one that belongs to the evolution module. If you look at the implementaiton of the method `database` that you are calling, both classes have the same logic (so, it doesn't matter which implementation is being used).

```
def database(name: String): Database = {
  databaseByName.getOrElse(name, throw new IllegalArgumentException(s"Could not find database for $name"))
}
```

This means that it will look for a key with the prefix `slick.dbs.<db name>`. Based on the error message you got

```
caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find database for play
    at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter.$anonfun$database$1(DBApiAdapter.scala:32)
```

you tried to look for a db config with the prefix `slick.dbs.play` and the stracktrace shows that in this case the implementation from evolutino module is being used.

To solve the issue you have two options:

- change the value `play` of the key `dbName` to `default`
- change the prefix `slick.dbs.default` to `slick.dbs.play`